# Gitlab: artifacts don't pass to child pipeline if job fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I pass artifacts from jobs in parent pipeline if some of jobs are failed?

There is my CI:

```
 .run-tests:
  image: maven-allure:jdk-15
  before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base
    - envsubst < ci-settings.xml > settings.xml
  artifacts:
    name: "${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
    paths:
      - mvn_log*
      - target*
    expire_in: 3 days
    when: always
  tags:
    - k8s

  smoke-tests:
  stage: smoke tests
  extends:
    - .run-tests
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: always
  script:
    - *smoke-tests

  sanity-tests:
  stage: sanity tests
  extends:
    - .run-tests
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: always
  script:
    - *sanity-tests
  
  patient-api-tests:
  stage: api tests
  extends:
    - .run-tests
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: manual
  variables:
    TELEGRAM_USER_ID: "xxxx"
  script:
    - *patient-api-tests
  needs: []
  
  patient-api-tests-trigger:
  stage: trigger jobs
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: always
  needs: ["patient-api-tests"]
  trigger:
    include: .trigger-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
    forward:
      yaml_variables: true
      pipeline_variables: true
  variables:
    PARENT_JOB_NAME: $CI_JOB_NAME
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID

  .upload-report:
  image: maven-allure:jdk-15
  variables:
    TELEGRAM_USER_ID: "xxx"
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base jq curl
    - envsubst < ci-settings.xml > settings.xml
    - cp -f settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
    - mkdir -p target/allure-results
    - mv target_*/allure-results/* target/allure-results
    - mvn allure:report
    - date
    - sh upload.sh
  tags:
    - k8s

  upload-sanity-smoke-report:
  extends: .upload-report
  stage: upload smoke sanity report (on failed)
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: always
      allow_failure: true
  needs: ["smoke-tests", "sanity-tests"]

upload-patient-report:
  extends: .upload-report
  stage: upload api report (always)
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline" && $PARENT_JOB_NAME == "patient-api-tests-trigger"
      when: always
  before_script:
    - echo $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
  needs:
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: sanity-tests
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: smoke-tests
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: patient-api-tests
```

If some of jobs fails, job **upload-patient-report** can't start with error:

```
This job could not start because it could not retrieve the needed
artifacts.
```

Maybe you know the way how can i get artifacts in child pipeline without needs?
I already tried to curl API artifacts by link like: [https://gitlab.ru/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}/download?job=smoke-tests](https://gitlab.ru/api/v4/projects/$%7BCI_PROJECT_ID%7D/jobs/artifacts/$%7BCI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%7D/download?job=smoke-tests)
And that way don't work in CI, i dont know why, i just got 404 error. But in CLI artifact is download

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify the `optional` parameter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional) for `needs` items.

```yaml
needs:
  - job: "jobname"
    pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
    optional: true
```

You can also help ensure the job can retrieve the artifacts by configuring the parent pipeline to (1) finish the required job before the child pipeline is triggered and (2) [specifying `artifacts:when:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactswhen) for the upstream jobs to be `always`.

Refer also to [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#pass-artifacts-to-a-downstream-pipeline-from-a-merge-request-pipeline) with particular attention to the [un]supported scenarios (for example, this is not supported with Merged Result pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

By having a graph pipeline, i have also come across this problem. However without specifying the `needs` keyword, there is no way to pass artifacts in this situation.